# Hamcrest assertThat doesnt work when project is moved

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I have made a test suite using hamcrest matchers and everything works fine until i move the project on a different machine.

The error i get is:

```
The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type MatcherAssert is not applicable  
for the arguments (Object, Matcher<Double>)
```

Any ideas why i get it and how to fix?

Also the error doesn't appear for all assertThat encounters, some are perceived as correct, even though they have a double for the matcher...

Comment: forgot to mention that i do know what the error means, just don't know why i get it...

Comment: Just to state the obvious, you need to find out what's different between the two environments. First thing I'd look at is the JVM version. And do you re-compile on the second machine, or just run the pre-compiled code?

Comment: As far as i know the JVMs are the same. And yeah, i re-compile, well trying to at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should state the the error you are getting is at compile-time not run-time. The issue is that `Double` is not a `super` of `Object`. So you call `assertThat(someObject, someDoubleMatcher)` doesn't meet the required signature at compile time. This will however work fine at runtime because the `Matcher` will check for type.

Could options...

```
// cast expected to object so that created matcher is Matcher<Object>
assertThat(myObject, CoreMatchers.equalTo((Object)myDouble));

// cast actual value to double so that both value and matcher are Double
assertThat((Double)myObject, equalTo(myDouble));

// cast Matcher to raw type so generics will be ignored
assertThat(myObject, (Matcher) equalTo(myDouble));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed it!
Also thanks for the tip about saying its a compile-time error and not a run-time error.